# How to use few subs in order to split the code procedure

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a downloader by halving it in steps so that each part works logically.

The code is divided into:

```
    public class Form1

 Public Shared link As String 'I'm sharing data with another form
```

I insert a url to download in the textchanged event of textbox:

```
If (My.Settings.Cartellasalvataggio = "") Then
            Label2.Text = "Download folder is missing"
            ' MsgBox("manca destinazione")
        Else
            If Clipboard.GetText.Contains("youtube") = False Then
                Label2.Text = "not a valid youtube link"
            Else
                If TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText Then
                    Label2.Text = "you already use it"
                Else

                    TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText
                    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.320youtube.com/v8/watch?v=" +
                                _TextBox1.Text.Replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", ""))
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

Then, in the document completed event I extract the download link:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
 label3.text=label3.text+"link download"
        Dim collection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
        Dim a As String
        For Each element As HtmlElement In collection
            If element.TagName = "A" Then
                a = element.GetAttribute("HREF")
                If a.Length > 70 Then
                    a.ToString.Replace(" - YouTube", "")
                    link = a
                 
                    If link IsNot Nothing Then
                        Title()

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

If the link variable is not empty then I activate the sub title:

```
Private Sub Title()
        label3.text=label3.text+"title+ "
        Dim wctitolo As New WebClient()
        wctitolo.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8

        Dim source As String = wctitolo.DownloadString(TextBox1.Text.Replace(" - YouTube", ""))
        Dim title As String = Regex.Match(source, "\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups("Title").Value
        Dim a As String = title.Replace(" - YouTube", "")
        Dim webdecode As String = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a)

        My.Settings.Titolo = String.Join("-", webdecode.Split(IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars))
        Label2.Text = "Getting title..- Step 3/4"
        Label1.Text = My.Settings.Titolo
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbLf + My.Settings.Titolo + Environment.NewLine)
        formcs.BetterListBox1.Items.Add(My.Settings.Titolo)
        My.Settings.Save()
        
        If Fileexist() Then

        Else
              If My.Settings.Titolo IsNot Nothing Then
                Download()
            End If
        End If
```

and sub FileExists () which returns true if the file exists and false if it does not exist. If it does not exist then, as dictated in private sub Title (), I activate the private sub Download ().

```
Public Function Fileexist() As Boolean
        Label3.Text = Label3.Text + "Checking if file exist+ "
        Dim result As Boolean
        Dim cartella = My.Settings.Cartellasalvataggio
        Dim filedidestinazione = Directory.GetFiles(cartella,
                                            My.Settings.Titolo + ".mp3",
                                              SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault()
        If filedidestinazione IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim answer As String
            answer = CType(MsgBox("File exist in" + vbLf + My.Settings.Cartellasalvataggio + "\" + My.Settings.Titolo + ".mp3" + vbLf + "Would you like to open the folder?", vbYesNo), String)
            If CType(answer, Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxResult) = vbYes Then
                Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select," & filedidestinazione)
                result = True
            Else
                result = False
               answer = CType(vbNo, String)
               
                Label2.Text = "File exist"

            End If
        End If
        Return result
    End Function
```

and at the end, the Download sub:

```
   Public WithEvents mclient As New WebClient
   Private Sub mClient_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles mclient.DownloadProgressChanged

       Try
           Label4.Text = (Val(e.BytesReceived) / 1048576).ToString("0.00") & "MB Scaricati"


           Label2.Text = "Download di " + My.Settings.Titolo + " in corso.."
       Catch ex As Exception
       End Try
   End Sub
Private Sub Download()
       Label3.Text = Label3.Text + "Download+ "
       Dim filepath As String = (My.Settings.Cartellasalvataggio + "\" + Label1.Text + ".mp3")
       mclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
       ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       mclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "")

       mclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(link), filepath)
   End Sub
```

I thought It was ok but, Look at this gif [Gif example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSmpI.gif)
is there an easy way I can concatenate these pieces of code in such a way that they work in a logical step by step without modifying to much the code?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give us a clue which method is producing that label text?

Comment: Hi, It's supposed to be updated  at the beginning of every private sub. Not all in once like you can see from the gif. it seems all private sub are being called together. How can I let them work without "rushing"?

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Title()
    label3.text=label3.text & "title+ "

Public Function Fileexist() As Boolean
    Label3.Text = Label3.Text & "Checking if file exist+ "

Private Sub Download()
   Label3.Text = Label3.Text & "Download+ "
```

The label is updating one after the other; it is just happening so fast that you can't see it. To prove it to yourself, put a breakpoint somewhere after the label code in each method and you will see the label text building. BTW, the ampersand is the usual vb concatenation symbol. Any + sign inside a string is not considered a concatenation character. "title+" for example.

I think you will find that your code is more readable if you can start using interpolated strings.

Comment: Your code is obvious just updating a label. That's not what I asked for

Comment: It is not my code; it is your code. You asked for an explanation of what is happening and I explained.

Comment: My code is a bit different than just setting a label text. By the way it is completely weird to me that they are working on top of each others. Look at my code, it s not possible that Download() is being processed basically 1 millisecond after Title(). I ll look further into it.

Comment: @Mattia The label _display_ is only updated when the UI is idle. The UI is **NOT** idle while the code in the `DocumentCompleted` event handler or any of the methods that it calls is being executed. So you can update the `Label.Text` Property as many times as you want in those methods, but the UI won't update the Label's _displayed_ value until the UI becomes idle again, i.e. after the code in the `Title()`, `Fileexist()` and `Download()` methods has been executed, control returned to the `DocumentCompleted` method and its `End Sub` statement is hit.

Comment: If you really need to, you can force the UI to redraw the `Label` by calling `Label3.Refresh` immediately after setting the `Label3.Text` Property. However, this won't do anything to help make the UI responsive while your code is running and blocking the UI thread from updating its display, or responding to user input. You probably should be considering using some sort of threading; maybe a background worker, Task or awaitable Async methods.

Comment: Hi @stevec, you reached the point. I need an async method.